# Updating a MongoDB document from two different clients using nodejs native driver

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nodes, node-mongodb-native

I have a `collection` of users which I'd like to update regularly using several different APIs (where each has its own rate limits etc).

So I have a few cron jobs with the following similar structure:

```
const cursor_i = db.collection('users').find();

while(await cursor_i.hasNext()){

    let user = await cursor_i.next();

    user.field_1 = 'Some New Stuff';

    const write_result = await db.collection('newusers').save(user);
    if(!write_result.result.ok){
        console.log(write_result);
    }
}
```

The problem is when a document is being updated at the same time, by more than one updater, only the last `save()` call would matter.

To clarify, consider the following code:

```
const cursor_1 = db.collection('users').find();
const cursor_2 = db.collection('users').find();

let user_cursor_1 = await cursor_1.next(); // user_cursor_1 has the first user in the collection
let user_cursor_2 = await cursor_2.next(); // user_cursor_2 has the first user in the collection

user_cursor_1.new_field_1 = 'ok';
const write_result = await db.collection('users').save(user_cursor_1);
if(!write_result.result.ok){
    console.log(write_result);
}

// first user in collection now has a new field named new_field_1 with the value 'ok'

user_cursor_2.new_field_2 = 'ok';
const write_result_2 = await db.collection('newusers').save(user_cursor_2);
if(!write_result_2.result.ok){
    console.log(write_result);
}

// first user in collection now has a new field named new_field_2 with the value 'ok' but DOES NOT have new_field_1 anymore
```

And so, the first user in the collection has been updated twice, but eventually will only have the effect of the second update.

I can think of a few ways to avoid it by implementing locks myself, but I'd guess MongoDB must have something to handle these cases.

Answer (score 0):

you should find users after updating the first cursor, like this :

```js
const cursor_1 = db.collection("users").find();
let user_cursor_1 = await cursor_1.next(); // user_cursor_1 has the first user in the collection

user_cursor_1.new_field_1 = "ok";
const write_result = await db.collection("users").save(user_cursor_1);
if (!write_result.result.ok) {
  console.log(write_result);
}


const cursor_2 = db.collection("users").find();
let user_cursor_2 = await cursor_2.next(); // user_cursor_2 has the first user in the collection

user_cursor_2.new_field_2 = "ok";
const write_result_2 = await db.collection("newusers").save(user_cursor_2);
if (!write_result_2.result.ok) {
  console.log(write_result);
}
```

Comment: thanks @vikash , but the whole point is that those two updates are done from a different process, possibly at the same time, so this won't help.

Comment: then in such case you have to use locks.

Comment: doesn't mongo provide such locks?